# Use returned array from jQuery $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a simple code that switches two values in DB and returns them back to jQuery, so I can switch them for user without need to refresh a apge.

The thing is, I return it as array, console.log shows array ok, but I have no idea how to get the data from array.

Return by PHP:

```
$data = array($id, $img1, $img2);
echo json_encode($data);
```

jQuery:

```
$.post("bg_images_ajax.php", "switch=yes&id="+id).done(function(data){
    $("#image-left-"+id).attr("src", "/images/backgrounds/"+data[1]).attr("alt", data[1]);
    $("#image-right-"+id).attr("src", "/images/backgrounds/"+data[2]).attr("alt", data[2]);
    console.log(data);
});
```

The data[1] worked almost every time I was working with Ajax, but here it looks like it takes the whole returned array as a simple string (***data[2] returns 6*** which is third character in the array ***["6", "blabla", "blalablala"]*** returned by console.log).

I tried to have the array be returned as:

```
["id" = "6", "img1" = "blabla", "img2" = "blalablala"]
```

And to use this to get what I needed:

```
data.img1
```

But this just returns undefined.

I checked the page about jQuery.post http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
But I am either blind or just too tired, as I do not see what am I doing wrong.

Ps.: I also tried putting format of response to jQuery code, but it did not work (as I am not really sure where exactly to place it, tried two places, as shown here (not simultaneously)).

```
$.post("bg_images_ajax.php", "switch=yes&id="+id, "json").done(function(data){
    $("#image-left-"+id).attr("src", "/images/backgrounds/"+data[1]).attr("alt", data[1]);
    $("#image-right-"+id).attr("src", "/images/backgrounds/"+data[2]).attr("alt", data[2]);
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```

Comment: Follow, @Quentin advice and add `header("Content-Type: application/json");` at the top of your PHP code. It will work.

Comment: I did and it works, but I know that $.post default data type is ***Intelligent Guess*** which should know that returned type is JSON. And I also know you should be able to change it, but have no bloody idea where to place it, when using ***.done(function...***. I just would like the PHP to be PHP and jQuery work as expected....

Comment: except that it is PHP job to provide the correct content type. For example, `hello.php`, browser has no way to know whether it is a normal HTML format, XML format, image, pdf, zip file, json, etc... There are million of possible format. It is PHP job to tell the browser that  what type of content the browser is viewing.

Comment: Thats true, but as I was using this http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started You just set content here, json_encode data in PHP and it works. SO I hope that setting JSON output for jQuery would work. So, is the ONLY option to set the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP is missing

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

and defaulting to sending `text/html`.

jQuery treats the result as a string of (invalid) HTML instead of parsing the JSON into the expected data structure.

---

Additionally, if you want an object (with named properties) instead of an array (which is accessed by numerical index), then you have to start with an associative array in PHP:

```
$data = array("id" => $id, "img1" => $img1, "img2" => $img2);
```

Comment: Ok, that worked, but why didn't ***json_encode*** work then? I use this: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started for longer queries, and that does not need header in PHP. Anyway, is there some other way to do it without that header?

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB — As I said, you sent jQuery some JSON but told it that the JSON was really HTML. You have to tell jQuery that the JSON is JSON if you want it to treat it as JSON.

Comment: Ok, so that me adding ***, 'json'*** to jQuery code had no effect? And to your edit: yes I tried associative array in PHP.

Comment: Edited my question with code I was trying to use to tell jQuery that response is in fact JSON.